# Cómo aplicar TextChanged en dos Forms al mismo tiempo?

Tags: c#, .net, formularios

Tengo dos Forms quiero hacer lo siguiente:

Estoy escribiendo en el `TextBox` de `Form1` quiero que se refleje en tiempo real en el `TextBox` que esta en el `Form2`

```cs
//Form1 

    private void txtTotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Hola, indica en la pregunta que has intentado hacer.

Comment: no tengo idea de como hacer esa parte, podrias sugerir alguna idea

Comment: @juancito0101 en este foro te puede ayudar, si algo me cuentas y miramos como hacerlo https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c0da598d-9697-4b96-a0f7-001912bcaaae/showing-2-textbox-texts-from-form1-to-labels-in-form2?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @ger estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema de restaurante el cual tiene una ventana Form1 para la vista del cajero donde se calcula el total a pagar, efectivo y cambio, el cual todo funciona bien, y una segunda pantalla muestra para la vista del cliente lo que seria el Form2, lo que quiero hacer es que es que en este Form2 se refleje a tiempo real el total a pagar, efectivo y cambio del Form1 sin necesidad de abrir cada rato el Form2 ya que este va estar siempre abierto. en otras palabras cada vez que cambie el textBox en el Form1 tambien cambie el TextBox en el Form2 al mismo tiempo

Comment: @RafaelAcosta estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema de restaurante el cual tiene una ventana Form1 para la vista del cajero donde se calcula el total a pagar, efectivo y cambio, el cual todo funciona bien, y una segunda pantalla muestra para la vista del cliente lo que seria el Form2, lo que quiero hacer es que es que en este Form2 se refleje a tiempo real el total a pagar, efectivo y cambio del Form1 sin necesidad de abrir cada rato el Form2 ya que este va estar siempre abierto. en otras palabras cada vez que cambie el textBox en el Form1 tambien cambie el TextBox en el Form2 al mismo tiempo